# Need to write Java converters

Tags: java

I need a help.
I have a task to do converters.

1) Code which should be able to do conversion from Decimal number to Binary.
(Result should be converted into Decimal number again)

2) Code which should be able to do conversion from Decimal number to Octal.
(Result should be converted into Decimal number again)

3) Code which should be able to do conversion from Decimal number to Hexadecimal.
(Result should be converted into Decimal number again)

Task forbid to write 2 single converters for example: first for Decimal -> Binary converter and second for Binary -> Decimal converter. **It should be 1 converter for each task: from Decimal -> Binary and after that the result converts from Binary -> Decimal and etc.**
User should be able to input numbers (except result).

I wrote code for 1st task but it isn't working correctly

```
package javalearn;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecimalToBinary {

    public static void DecimalToBinary() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int decimal = 0, n = 0;
    int num, i, var = 0;
    int[] intArray;
    intArray = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Enter your decimal number: ");
    num = in.nextInt();
    for (i = 0; num > 0; i++) {
        intArray[i] = num % 2;
        num = num / 2;
    }
    System.out.println("Converted decimal number into binary: ");
    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        System.out.print(intArray[i]);

    }

    System.out.println();
    // Next

    while (true) {
        if (intArray[i] == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            int temp = intArray[i] % 10;
            decimal += temp * Math.pow(2, n);
            intArray[i] = intArray[i] / 10;
            n++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(intArray[i]);            
}
```

Comment: For which decimal number is it failing?

Comment: *1) Code which should be able to do conversion from Decimal number to Binary. (Result should be converted into Decimal number again)* -- What is the point of converting it to Binary then? Can you share some samples of input and output

Comment: For any, for example user will input a number and then it should be converted. I mean I need to use Scanner.

Comment: Hi, I'm asking just to make sure that if you are trying to find out the algorithms to implement them? Can you use the built-in static methods of `Integer` class, `toBinaryString`, `toOctalString`, and `toHexString`? There is a detailed explanation besides a demo on http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html if you are on the former.

Comment: No, I should write code with custom logic (task rules).

Answer (score 1):

You get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you count `i` down to -1 in your second `for` condition and start using it again in your while loop `if(intArray[i] == 0)`. You could use a temporary variable to keep the `i` value and assign it back to `i` after counting down.

Somthing like:

```
int temp = i;
for(...){
....
}
i = temp;
while(true){
...
}
```

Good luck with your assignment.